# Centralising Bootstrap Columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm working with Bootstrap to create a responsive site and have three divs of equal size that need centering on the page. However, they're focusing more to the left hand-side of the page.

**HTML:**

```
        <div id="team-test">

            <div class="team-desktop container">
                <div class="team-profile col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                    <h3 class="team-name">Person 1</h3>
                    <img class="team-image" src="assets/img/team-2.png" alt=""/>
                    <p class="team-info-role"></p>
                    <p class="team-info"></p>
                </div>

                <div class="team-profile col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                    <h3 class="team-name"></h3>
                    <img class="team-image" src="assets/img/team-1.png" alt=""/>
                    <p class="team-info-role"></p>
                    <p class="team-info"></p>
                </div>

                <div class="team-profile col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                    <h3 class="team-name"></h3>
                    <img class="team-image" src="assets/img/team-3.png" alt=""/>
                    <p class="team-info-role"></p>
                    <p class="team-info"></p>
                </div> 
            </div>

        </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.team-desktop {
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0 auto;
}

#team-test {
    text-align:center;
}

.team-profile {
    width:350px;
    text-align:center;
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color:#f7f7f7;
    border-radius:10px;
    margin-right:20px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    float:none;
}
```

[Website Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47iuQ.png)

I have tried using Bootstraps 'offset' which does center them, however, it makes the divs flow vertically; instead of having all three on the same column.

Comment: The Bootstrap grid is based on 12 columns. You have three divs with `col-md-3`, so 3x3=9 which is < 12.

Comment: I tried adding another div to makeup the 12 columns, as well as changing them to col-4's but the last div is positioned below the rest of them.

https://gyazo.com/1bbbe2ac98b5130a8fee251e771e8f69

Comment: You have to be careful when you modify bootstrap columns as their intended to be used in a particular way, i.e. set gutter, percentage width, etc. All of which you're overriding with `.team-profile`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah Bootstrap grid is 12 column. You used col-md-3 which overrides col-sm-4. You don't need to apply any CSS except for your custom styles. You also didn't include .row class to wrap all your columns inside container.

Check out the code below. and codepen link.

```
<div id="team-test">

            <div class="team-desktop container">
              <div clas="row">
                <div class="team-profile col-sm-4">
                    <h3 class="team-name">Person 1</h3>
                    <img class="team-image img-responsive img-circle center-block" src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt=""/>
                    <p class="team-info-role">Thsi is the role for smaple user. Add more content here and it will be long.</p>
                    <p class="team-info"> This is sample user info</p>
                </div>

                <div class="team-profile col-sm-4">
                    <h3 class="team-name">Person 2</h3>
                    <img class="team-image img-circle" src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt=""/>
                    <p class="team-info-role">Thsi is the role for smaple user. You can add whatever you like here.</p>
                    <p class="team-info"> This is sample user info</p>
                </div>

                <div class="team-profile col-sm-4">
                    <h3 class="team-name"> Person 3</h3>
                    <img class="team-image img-responsive img-circle" src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt=""/>
                    <p class="team-info-role">Thsi is the role for smaple user and here also and it will expand</p>
                    <p class="team-info"> This is sample user info</p>
                </div> 
              </div>
            </div>

        </div>
```

Check sample Codepen at http://codepen.io/piyushpatel2005/pen/NpmEMq

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Need to have a read up on Bootstrap properly, didn't know that specifying sizes of divs would mess up the columns. Thanks for the help. @everyone

Answer (score 1):

If you are using (or are willing to upgrade to) Bootstrap 4 - it has the ability to auto-size columns for you by just using the "col" class without specifying a size.

The amount of columns you add to a row will be given an equal distribution across the grid.

https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#auto-layout-columns

Answer (score 0):

As seen in your comment right below your question and this screenshot https://gyazo.com/1bbbe2ac98b5130a8fee251e771e8f69, I believe you may wanna add a *.row* inside the *.container*, for the 4th block to be inline (FYI, *.row* has negative margins, tryna inspect it).

I also don't see why you wanna have those custom CSS (overriding width of the col element, making container inline-block ...)? These would break Bootstrap grid for sure :-)

Plus, if you want it to be 3 blocks that fill up the entire space, change *.col-md-3* to *.col-md-4*. Or furthermore, if you wanna make it those columns that small, I would suggest reduce the size of *.container* (or *.team-desktop*) to equal the sum of those 3 small cols.

So it should be something like this

```
<div id="team-test">
    <div class="team-desktop container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="team-profile col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                <h3 class="team-name">Person 1</h3>
                <img class="team-image" src="assets/img/team-2.png" alt=""/>
                <p class="team-info-role"></p>
                <p class="team-info"></p>
            </div>

            <div class="team-profile col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                <h3 class="team-name"></h3>
                <img class="team-image" src="assets/img/team-1.png" alt=""/>
                <p class="team-info-role"></p>
                <p class="team-info"></p>
            </div>

            <div class="team-profile col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                <h3 class="team-name"></h3>
                <img class="team-image" src="assets/img/team-3.png" alt=""/>
                <p class="team-info-role"></p>
                <p class="team-info"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest working with the grid system and not fighting it by overwriting most of it like you have with your `.team-profile` class. If you're aware of the repercussions, go ahead.

As others have noted 3 columns that are 3 columns wide equals 9 columns and not 12. Which isn't a problem, unless you want to use an offset class to center. Offset column classes come in whole column values and as we know 3 / 2 = 1.5. So you'll need to create a custom offset class to center.

Below is a generic demo of working with the Bootstrap [Grid System](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) and how to center a group of odd numbered columns with a custom offset column class.

** Make sure to click **Full Screen** so the columns are not stacked.*

```css
@import url( 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css' );

/* Following three selectors illustration purposes. */
.row:nth-child( 1 ) {
  background-color: gold;
}
.row:nth-child( 2 ) {
  background-color: skyblue;
}
.item {
  background-color: rgba( 252, 252, 252, 0.7 );
}

/* Custom offset class */
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .col-sm-offset-1-5 {
    margin-left: 12.49999%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container"> 

  <div class="row">
    
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="item">
        Column 1
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class=" col-sm-3">
      <div class="item">
        Column 2
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class=" col-sm-3">
      <div class="item">
        Column 3
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class=" col-sm-3">
      <div class="item">
        Column 4
      </div>
    </div>
    
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    
    <div class="col-sm-offset-1-5 col-sm-3">
      <div class="item">
        Column 1
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class=" col-sm-3">
      <div class="item">
        Column 2
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class=" col-sm-3">
      <div class="item">
        Column 3
      </div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Eventually the columns will stack as that's typically what needs to happen in responsive design on the smaller viewports.