# Bootstrap inline form not working on chrome

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an issue with bootstrap `form-inline` which does not work properly on Chrome (i-e, the Button goes below other fields on Chrome, but it should be inline), please see the link of the page [here](https://monsitexemple.fr/form.php)

Here is the code of the form:

```
  <div class="container">

    <form class="form-inline" method="post" action="resultats.php" onsubmit="return submitForm(this);">

      <div class="habon">

        <div>

          <label for="ami" class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="origine" value="ami" id="anywhere">
            N'importe où
          </label>
          &emsp;
          <label for="ami" class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="origine" value="ami" id="anytime">
            N'importe quand
          </label>

        </div>


        <div>

            <div class="form-group">


              <div>
                <label for="tags">De</label>
                <div>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="tags" name="tags" placeholder="Paris">
                </div>
              </div>


            </div>

            <div class="form-group">


              <div>
                <label for="tags2">&Agrave;</label>
                <div>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="tags2" name="tags2" placeholder="Londres">
                </div>
              </div>

            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="datepicker1">Départ</label>
              <div>
                <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="datepicker1" name="datepicker1" placeholder="DD MM YYYY">
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="datepicker2">Retour</label>
              <div>
                <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="datepicker2" name="datepicker2" placeholder="DD MM YYYY">
              </div>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group"> <!--  Ne sert à rien  ?-->
              <label for="butt"><br></label>
              <div>
                  <button type="submit" id="butt" class="btn btn-default btn-block">Envoyer</button>
              </div>
            </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </form>

  </div>
```

And here is the corresponding css:

```
form{
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 20%;
}

body{

    background-image: url("red2.jpg");

}


.habon {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1);
  padding-bottom:2%;
  padding-left:2%;
  padding-right:2%;
}
```

I have tried a solution from another post, which is to replace the URLs links to CDN with `//` intead of `https://` or `http://`, but it still the same.

Do you have any idea where this problem comes from ?

Thank you

Comment: What exactly isn't working?

Comment: Sorry, the button "Envoyer" goes below the other fileds on Chrome

Comment: Button doesn't need to be wrapped in `.form-group` div, http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-example

Comment: @Morpheus if I remove the `form-group` div around the button, it goes below other fields for both browsers, which is not what I want

Comment: It's because you applied absolute positioning to your `<form>` element. Typical absolute positioning is a no-no when you want a responsive site.

Comment: And also because you have `.btn-block` class against the button. Just remove it, unwrap from `.form-group` div and it will work

Comment: The absolute positioning is part of the problem.  If you can, give the form a set width (or min-width) that is wide enough to accommodate all of the fields.

Comment: Essentially, if you remove your custom CSS, everything works fine. It's not Bootstrap inline forms that don't work, it's your CSS (and possibly your extra markup) that is working against intended Bootstrap usage.

Comment: @hungerstar Indeed, but now that I removed the "form" part of my css file, the form is not centered and the div is extended to the right...

Comment: @aurelSon you can use the grid to center and control form group widths. Are there going to be additional rows of form fields?

Comment: @hungerstar nope, it's just this simple form on this page.

Comment: @hungerstar ok I added the class "col-md-9" to the form, it's the good size now, but the centering on the page remains a problem

Comment: You can use offset column classes to push it to the right and center it. The thing is, there's twelve columns and you're using 9 which leaves 3 unused columns. The offset column classes only use whole numbers and not halves. You would have to use 8 or 10 columns for the form width and offset by 1 or 2 columns. Or you could create a custom offset column class like I suggest in [**this answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43236694/centralising-bootstrap-columns/43237226#43237226).

Comment: Though you might want to use a [**horizontal form**](http://getbootstrap.com/css/?#forms-horizontal) as the form [**might not reflow like you want it to**](https://jsfiddle.net/64u59u7o/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a work around, just add a flexbox display in the div that wrap the entire form it will put everything inline by default :

```
<div style ="display:flex">

            <div class="form-group">


              <div>
                <label for="tags">De</label>
                <div>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="tags" name="tags" placeholder="Paris">
                </div>
              </div>


            </div>

            <div class="form-group">


              <div>
                <label for="tags2">&Agrave;</label>
                <div>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="tags2" name="tags2" placeholder="Londres">
                </div>
              </div>

            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="datepicker1">Départ</label>
              <div>
                <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="datepicker1" name="datepicker1" placeholder="DD MM YYYY">
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="datepicker2">Retour</label>
              <div>
                <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="datepicker2" name="datepicker2" placeholder="DD MM YYYY">
              </div>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group"> <!--  Ne sert à rien  ?-->
              <label for="butt"><br></label>
              <div>
                  <button type="submit" id="butt" class="btn btn-default btn-block">Envoyer</button>
              </div>
            </div>

        </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this tip, everything goes inline now, only problem, it's ugly, I have to add a space between fields and adjust the button so it's centered

Comment: You're welcome ! Indeed, you have to reformat the design following your needs.

Comment: This worked for me, only I used bootstrap's `.d-flex` utility class.